# Timer inside a listbox c#

Tags: c#, timer, listbox

So I am currently working on a program in which I need to have a timer attached to each item inside of a list box, I have that working, but I can't select any of the items, is there a way to be able to select the items but also have a timer displayed to each item in the list box?

Update:

when adding the item to a new list box here is the code that I have:

```
private void btnSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string name = lsbScheduled.SelectedItem.ToString();// saves the selected item to a string
                string newItem = (moveItem(name));//calls the method and passes the variable to it
                tmrCheckedIn.Enabled = true;
                tmrCheckedIn.Start();
                newItem += "      " + "00:00:00";
                lsbScheduled.Items.Remove(name);// removes the item from the list
                lsbCheckedIn.Items.Add(newItem); //adds the item to the list          
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
            }
        }
here is my code for the tick event: 

 private void tmrCheckedIn_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = lsbCheckedIn.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string item = lsbCheckedIn.Items[i].ToString();
            string[] line = item.Split();
            string time = line[8];

            Time oldTime = new Time();
            oldTime.StartTime = time;

            lsbCheckedIn.Items.Remove(item);
            string newTime = string.Format(line[0] + " " + line[1] + " " +line[2] + "      " + "{0:c}", oldTime.EndTime);
            lsbCheckedIn.Items.Add(newTime);


            oldTime = null;

        }

    }

and here is my class that I use to increase the timer:
 public class Time
    {
        private int seconds, minutes, hours;
        string startTime, endTime;

       public Time()
        {
            seconds = 00;
            minutes = 00;
            hours = 00;
            startTime = " ";
            endTime = "";
        }

        public string StartTime
        {
            set { startTime = value;
            CalcNewTime();
            }
            get { return startTime; }
        }

        public string EndTime
        {
            set { endTime = value; }
            get { return endTime; }
        }

        public int Hours
        {
            set { hours = value; }
            get { return hours; }
        }

        public int Minutes
        {
            set { minutes = value; }
            get { return minutes; }
        }

        public int Second
        {
            set { seconds = value; }
            get { return seconds; }
        }

        private void CalcNewTime()
        {
            const int LIMIT = 6, CONVERT = 10;

            string[] divisions = startTime.Split(':');
            hours = Convert.ToInt32(divisions[0]);
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(divisions[1]);
            seconds = Convert.ToInt32(divisions[2]);

            int hoursTens = hours / CONVERT;
            int hoursOnes = hours % CONVERT;
            int minutesTens = minutes / CONVERT;
            int minuteOnes = minutes % CONVERT;

            seconds += 1;
            int secondTens = seconds / CONVERT;
            int secondOnes = seconds % CONVERT;



            if (secondTens >= LIMIT)
            {
                secondTens = 0;
                secondOnes = 0;
                minutes += 1;

                minutesTens = Minutes / CONVERT;
                minuteOnes = minutes % CONVERT;
                if (minutesTens >= LIMIT)
                {
                    minutesTens = 0;
                    minuteOnes = 0;
                    hours += 1;

                    hoursTens = hours / CONVERT;
                    hoursOnes = Hours % CONVERT;
                }
            }
            endTime = Convert.ToString(hoursTens + hoursOnes + ":" + minutesTens + minuteOnes + ":" + secondTens + secondOnes);
        }

    }
```

in programming a windows form application using visual studio 2010 im using the timer that you can select from the toolbox. I need to be able to select the items in the list box but right now i can because im constantly adding and removing items from the list box. I want the time that is displayed in the list box to go up, but i also need it so that i can select the item in the list box.

Comment: Please show sample code and some screen shots of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you programming WPF? What is this Timer you are referring to?

Comment: Timer like a timer **class** or timer like a label showing a number counting down? Your question makes very little sense at the moment.

Comment: timer as in counting up not down

Comment: You might like to look at the `StopWatch` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). This is designed to be started and return a time since start. This might save a lot of the code you are using since you can just get a `TimeSpan` out of it and use `ToString` to format it as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're removing items from the listbox, and then adding new ones. This is why items do not remain selected. Instead, just replace the items.

```
lsbCheckedIn.Items[i] = newTime;
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems like the reason. The other option if removing and adding new is necessary for any reason is to check if what you are removing is selected and if so select the new one after you have added it.